# time calculation within LINQ

Tags: linq, datetime, timespan

I want a linq query to return a calculated timespan,
i have used the timespan function before, but im not sure how to incorporate it into linq.
Basically the linq is returning a datetime field which i want to subtract from the current datetime to get days and hours.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you give an example?

Comment: should ahve mentioned that I need the result straight from the linq query and not calculated afterwards if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
from s in something
select DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.DateField)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the code below returns a date opened field, i want to calculate how many days the case is open and put it into a gridview.

var query2 = from cs in db.tblCases
                             where cs.date_closed.HasValue == false
                             select new
                             {
                               cs.date_case_opened),

```
                         };

    gvReport.DataSource =
                query2.Select(o => new {o.time });

            gvReport.DataBind();
            lbCount.Text = "Days open: " + ???
```